# Replace jQuery animation with Angular animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

One of my ng-views has a next structure

```
<div class="container-fluid wrapper">
    <aside ng-if="asideMenu">
        <div ng-include src="'html/partials/stats/aside.html'"></div>
    </aside>
    <section>
        <div ng-include src="'html/partials/stats/grid.html'"></div>
        <div ng-include src="'html/partials/stats/tabs.html'"></div>
    </section>
```

where I have a grid and tabs as a major content and if user wants he can open aside bar. The function to open aside bar is

```
        $scope.asideMenu = false;
        $scope.aside = function () {

            getTree();

            var section = document.getElementsByTagName("section");
            var aside = document.getElementsByTagName("aside");

            $scope.asideMenu = !$scope.asideMenu;

            if ($scope.asideMenu == true) {

                $(section).animate({
                    'width': '84%'
                }, 500, function () {
                    $(aside).animate({
                        'width': '15%'
                    });
                });
            }
            else {

                $(aside).animate({
                    'width': '0%'
                }, 1000, function () {
                    $(section).animate({
                        'width': '100%'
                    });
                });
            }
        };
```

So currently I'm using jQuery animation to open aside menu and shrink major content.

The question is simple, what is the best way to replace jQuery animation to Angular & CSS animation (without any additional dependencies and libs)??

This is [simple example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ocULoYWnCzr7uZZxnBoK?p=preview) of my page

Comment: can use ng-class and css animations. Question is both too broad and asks for opinions...both of which are off topic

Comment: @charlietfl did you mean something like this `ng-class="asideMenu: 'class1', "!asideMenu: 'class2'`?

Comment: properties/values are reversed

Comment: @charlietfl `ng-if="asideMenu" ng-class="{'aside-open': asideMenu, 'aside-close': !asideMenu}"` thanks a lot! it works for me better then lagging jQuery

Comment: Your question is a bit too broad to give a good answer for, but looking at the animation in your code, you can achieve that easily with CSS [transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) and class toggling (discussed in the above comments).